# Webmin/Virtualmin - Handling with large file - Internal Server Error

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysqli, webmin

I'm using a PHP script to insert the unique value of an array into the database. Here's the script

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $df = $_POST['df'];

    $arr = array();
    $file = fopen('files/'.$df.'.csv', 'r');
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
        $arr[] = $line[2];
    }
    $arruniq = array_unique($arr);
    fclose($file);
    $arr_count = count($arr);

    $time = strtotime(date_default_timezone_get());
    $ts = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "pass", "tab");
    if ($mysqli === false) {
        die("ERROR: DB could not connect. ");
    }

    $sqlins = "insert into tab (created_time, uniq_id) values (?, ?);";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $arr_count; $i++) {
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sqlins)) {
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $ts, $arruniq[$i]);
            $stmt->execute();
        } else {
            echo "ERROR: Could not prepare query";
        }
    }
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

The script is reading a CSV file, unique the values and insert into the database. Here's the problem, the script works fine if the file size is smaller, but if I use a larger file I'm getting this "500 internal server error".

No error is displaying or logged in the server PHP logs as well as apache logs.

I even increased the execution time of the script and memory limit of the script by using `ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');` and `max_execution_time` headers, which also didn't work.

Comment: Did you update `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` also?

Comment: yes, i set that too `upload_max_filesize 200M` and `post_max_size 200M`, but no changes

Comment: We have to make sure the issue is really in csv file or someother causing. Where did you checked the logs? has the access log making entry for your page load?

Comment: this is the error i'm getting from apache2 error logs `[fcgid:warn] [pid 3221] mod_fcgid: process 4423 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL`
`[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3220] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down`

Comment: and I 've changed `FcgidConnectTimeout` from 20 to 500

Comment: You need to stop manually checking for errors. Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439) and [Should I manually check for errors when calling “mysqli_stmt_prepare”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62216426/1839439)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with execution time of the script.
Since i'm using webmin/ virtualmin **max_execution_time** header didn't work. So I've changed that in the virtualmin server

```
virtualmin server -> server configuration -> website options -> Maximum PHP script run time
```

Now the issue is solved, But it takes longer time for executing script.

Answer (score 0):

It should be faster if you use prepared statements and transactions.

```
$mysqli->begin_transaction();
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tab (created_time, uniq_id) values (?, ?);");
foreach($arruniq as $item) {
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $ts, $item);
    $stmt->execute();
}
$mysqli->commit();
```

Prepared statements when used correctly give you slight performance improvement, because the server doesn't need to parse the SQL every time and the transactions save you some time because the `commit` is not called after each row.