# Why am i getting the following Syntax error, unexpected ';' C:\xampp...on line 18

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

I do not understand why I am getting an error in the code below

> unexpected ';' C:\xampp...on line 18

```
if($stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO facturas (id_factura, id_depositante, beneficiario, endereço, cell, descriçao, montante) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'){
  $stmt->bind_param('ssssisi', $id_factura, $nome, $_POST['beneficiario'], 
  $_POST['endereço'], $_POST['cell'], $_POST['descriçao'], $_POST['montante']); //here is the line 18
  $stmt->execute();
}
```

It seems like it was not expecting the end of the `$stmt->bind_param` line.

Comment: Your if-statement is has two opening parenthesis, but only one closing one. `if(...prepare(...){`

Comment: You need to stop manually checking for errors. Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439) and [Should I manually check for errors when calling “mysqli_stmt_prepare”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62216426/1839439)