# PHP error with prepared statements using OOP

Tags: php, sql, oop, mysqli

I have recently followed a tutorial playlist on PHP OOP by mmtuts on youtube, but he used PDO and I don't and I am getting an error when I try to implement the code in my project.

My code:

```
//In file with class 'Article'.
public function deleteArticle($id) {
     $conn = $this->connect();
     $sql = "UPDATE article SET deleted=1 WHERE row_id=?";
     $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
     $stmt->execute();
     $result = $stmt->get_result();
     return $result;
}

//In file with class 'DBConn'.
public function connect() {
   $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '','nicms');
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }
   return $conn;
}

//In file with class 'articleContr'.
public function showDeleteArticle($id) {
   if ($this->deleteArticle($id)
       echo "Article has successfully been deleted.";
   else 
     echo "Failed to delete article.";
}
```

The error is that the article DOES get deleted but the method showDeleteArticle gives the message 'Failed to delete article'. even though the article has been deleted.

Comment: The PHP documentation says get_result only returns values for SELECT queries and false for all other query types.  Have you read the documentation for examples of what to do when you're doing INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE queries?https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

Comment: You need to stop manually checking for errors. Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439) and [Should I manually check for errors when calling “mysqli_stmt_prepare”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62216426/1839439)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is wrong on so many levels (as you would expect from a youtube tutorial), but the main problem is that the method showDeleteArticle() is wrong and misleading.

There is **no reason** for this method to be at all. Which is proven by the fact the other answer is accepted. The offered code **always** returns a **true**-like value, hence the condition inside showDeleteArticle() becomes useless. One could rewrite it as

```
public function showDeleteArticle($id) {
    echo "Article has successfully been deleted.";
}
```

as it will never enter the else part anyway.

Let alone any Controller should never blurt out any data directly, not through View. Least after a POST request after which there **must** be a redirect, not output.

Comment: I understand what you mean but how should I check if the sql statement succeeded or not?

Comment: Not at all. Please see my answer that explains it: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/243749/101565

Answer (score -2):

the error is that you return a $result,
this will only work when using a select statement. But on an insert, update, delete
there is no need for the $result, the $result is NOT a boolean and that is why it does not work in the if statement.
You should return the $stmt because and check that in the if statement

Change your code to this and it should work:

```
    protected function unSetArticle($id) {
        $conn = $this->connect();
        $sql = "UPDATE article SET deleted=1 WHERE row_id=?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
    }//Method unSetArticle.
```

Comment: this code is essentially useless. Just like the other variant that always returned false, this one always returns true, which is not an improvement whatsoever.