# mysqli Prepared statements with multiple joins keeps returning false

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am supposed to design an exam server system and I keep getting errors while I am trying to prepare the statement using mysqli's prepare function. I am using php to connect to sql represented by the $conn variable(it does connect to the DB), and I have tried the same exact statements in mysql workbench and it works fine. Here is the code I have written:

```
$stmtTempTable = $conn->prepare("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE front_action_temp
                        SELECT * FROM front_action
                        WHERE time_offset > 0");
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT event_name, status, day_of_week, week_of_year, event_year, start_time, time(start_time + 
                        time_offset) as end_time, machine_group
                        FROM front_weekly
                        LEFT JOIN front_event ON front_weekly.event_id=front_event.event_id
                        LEFT JOIN front_daily ON front_event.event_id=front_daily.event_id
                        LEFT JOIN front_group ON front_daily.group_id=front_group.group_id
                        LEFT JOIN front_action_temp ON front_action_temp.event_id=front_event.event_id
                        WHERE day_of_week=? and week_of_year=? and event_year=?");

if ($stmt === false){
    die('Unable to execute');
} else {
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $dayOfWeek, $weekNumber, $year);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

I keep getting false for $stmt. Any ideas why?

Comment: `$stmtTempTable` never gets executed.

Comment: You need to stop manually checking for errors. Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439) and [Should I manually check for errors when calling “mysqli_stmt_prepare”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62216426/1839439)

Comment: `$stmtTempTable` does not need to be prepared, you aren't passing any placeholders/values.

Answer (score 1):

You are only `prepare()`ing the `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE...` but not `execute()`ing it. The second statement fails because the table does not exist.