# Mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in Website Building ON SYNOLOGY NAS

Tags: php, mysqli, mariadb, synology

I transferred a small service site from the AlterVista portal to my NAS Synology, the same code that ran fine now no longer runs on my NAS. From connection error to MariaDB. I have already read your forums about this problem but this is another system (not a pc but a nas with its own applications). I am using port 3307 because mariadb10 is listening on that port. (While mariadb 5 is listening on port 3306 You can also check)

On the NAS I have already installed MariaDB, PHP, PHP admin (which connects well to mariadb), Apache HTTP Server 2.2, and all the drivers and options that require the installation of PHP 5,7 (mysqli, pdo driver, and other options).

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$USERNAME = "root";
$PASSWORD = "xxxxxxx";  //null  
$DBSERVER = "127.0.0.1:3307";   //127.0.0.1:3306  mariadb5
$DBNAME = "miodb";

if(!($db_connection = new mysqli($DBSERVER, $USERNAME, $PASSWORD, $DBNAME)))
   die('Connect Error (' . $db_connection->connect_errno . ') '. $db_connection->connect_error);

if(!($db_selection = $db_connection->select_db($DBNAME)))
   die ("Errore nella selezione del DB.");

$query = $db_connection->query("SELECT * FROM MATERIALE");
while($cicle=$query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $url=$cicle['FOTO'];
    echo "<tr>
              <td>".$cicle['CODICEARTICOLO']."</td>
              <td><img src='".$url."' width='50' height='50' /> </td>
              <td>".$cicle['DESCRIZIONE']."</td>
              <td>".$cicle['PREZZO']." Euro</td>
          </tr>";
}
$query->close();
$db_connection->close();
?>
```

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in >/volume1/web/listino.php on line 111 Warning: mysqli::select_db(): Couldn't fetch mysqli >in /volume1/web/listino.php on line 114 Errore nella selezione del DB.

Comment: mysqli_connect(host, username, password, dbname, port, socket)

please follow this

Comment: leave it empty follow below comment. also check that your connect should not be closed before querying or too early. i.e
$db_connection->close();

Comment: Please do not use PHP 5. You should also not be using Apache 2.2. There is Apache 2.4 available.

Answer (score -1):

Please Try this

```
$db_host        = '127.0.0.1';
$db_user        = 'root';
$db_pass        = '';
$db_database    = 'database_name';
$db_port        = '3306';

$connection = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_database,$db_port);
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in >/volume1/web/listino.php on line 120 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to >a member function select_db() on boolean in /volume1/web/listino.php:126 >Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /volume1/web/listino.php on line 126.       
                                                                        could you use the same syntax as the code I posted above please? ;) this in order not to upset the code.

Comment: does your connection is successful?
Can you please share line 120 with me?

Comment: no it doesn't ;120 line: $db_connection = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_database,$db_port);   FATAL ERROR because in this moment we are not manage the error connection. in my code it's managed !!

Comment: have you change your db port accordingly?

Comment: mysqli_connect accepts two parameter first is db connection & second the name of db like this
 mysqli_select_db($db_connection , 'db_name')

Comment: no i did not changed port on mariaDB !!! could you explain me how make it in MariaDB10 software? (i know mariadb10 default port is 3307), but we need verify it !!

Comment: Does your connection is successful?

Comment: please use this  mysqli_select_db($db_connection , 'db_name')  instead of select_db() for selecting database

Comment: Yes you can do !! do you have teamviewer or anydesk for connection?

Comment: can you please provide me ftp account?

Comment: i prefare you enter by my laptop connected to my NAS. so i can see your fixed.

Comment: Sorry Can't access via any desktop tool except filezilla

Comment: can you please tell me teamviewer id & password

Comment: 831 366 230 ; fuu178

Comment: Hello Akram i read you page, in synology nas the file my.cnf is in this path: /var/packages/MariaDB/etc , expecially in my nas the file is not present i created it using VI editor but i don't know what to put inside. (in your page you wrote in maria db 10 port and bind they not work).
So what i must write in this file?

Answer (score -1):

I modified in my graphic console Synology Nas:

1. on (PHP core setting port 3307 instead of 3306).
2. in PHP code port 3307 value.
3. enabled on maria db10 flag on TCP/IP port setting on 3307(default)

   ```
    <?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $USERNAME = "root";
    $PASSWORD = "password"; //null X
    $DBSERVER = "127.0.0.1";    //127.0.0.1:3306
    $DBNAME = "miodb";
    $DB_PORT = '3307';
    $SOCKET = "/run/mysqld/mysqld10.sock";   //not necessary

    $db_connection = new mysqli($DBSERVER, $USERNAME, $PASSWORD, $DBNAME, $DB_PORT);

    $query = $db_connection->query("SELECT * FROM MATERIALE");
    while ($cicle = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $url = $cicle['FOTO'];
        echo "<tr>
                <td>" . $cicle['CODICEARTICOLO'] . "</td>
                <td><img src='" . $url . "' width='50' height='50' /> </td>
                <td>" . $cicle['DESCRIZIONE'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $cicle['PREZZO'] . " Euro</td>
            </tr>";
    }
    $query->close();
    $db_connection->close();
   ```

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. Also, take a look at [answer]

Comment: You need to stop manually checking for errors. Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439) and [Should I manually check for errors when calling “mysqli_stmt_prepare”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62216426/1839439)

Comment: I fixed your answer a little bit, but I still think it's slightly unclear. I barely see any difference between this and the code in question.

Comment: Also, word of advice: Don't use `while` loop. It can be quite confusing. Try `foreach($query as $cicle)` instead

Comment: Why did you roll it back?

Answer (score -2):

You need to provide all six arguments when connecting to MariaDB on your Synology NAS. The sixth parameter is the socket name which you should use.

The correct code for mysqli connection would be this:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
// Please do not connect as root!
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'miodb', 3307, '/run/mysqld/mysqld10.sock');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset
```

If you are only starting with PHP development then I recommend learning PDO instead of mysqli. Using PDO you would connect this way:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=miodb;charset=utf8mb4;unix_socket=/run/mysqld/mysqld10.sock", 'root', 'password', [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
]);
```