# parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, jsonencoder

i'm new in web develope and now get the error in ajax..
i have a page (things.php) for get info from users and then send info via ajax to authenticate.php, and in this page call db.class.php for push and fetch data from database,

now i want to fetch data from users db, when things_register_btn in things.php clicked.

my problem is the when "things_register_btn" clicked, the chrome show error in console:

```
parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token ﻿ in JSON at position 0
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
    at l (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
```

and when change datatype to "text" console show me :
{"id":1,"password":"test"}
the data fetch from database

here is my code :

> things.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>


 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../project/css/new/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">     
    <link href="../project/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../project/css/jquery.md.bootstrap.datetimepicker.style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets2/css/vazir.css" rel="stylesheet">
    

   </head>

   <body>
   <div class="container-fluid h-100" >

    <div class="row">
        <div class="container-fluid col-2 bg-light align-items-start justify-content-start">
             <h1 class="text-right my-3" ></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid col-10 bg-light align-items-start justify-content-start">
            <h4 class="text-right my-3" >ثبت شیء</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row h-100">

        <div class="container col-2 h-100 bg ">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1 p-0"></div>
                <div class="col-10 p-0">
                <div class="container p-3">
                    <a  href="#" class="text-white h5"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="container p-3 border-light border mb-3">
                    <a  href="#" class="text-white h5"> ثبت شیء </a>
                </div>
                <div class="container p-3 border-light border mb-3">
                    <a href="#" class="text-white h5"> تحویل شیء </a>
                </div>
                <div class="container p-3 border mb-3">
                    <a  href="#" class="text-white h5"> گزارش گیری </a>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 p-0"></div>
            </div>
        <!--    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 container-fluid">
            <nav class ="navbar justify-content-center align-items-start">

                <ul class ="navbar-nav">
                    <li class ="nav-item container col-12 p-3">
                        <a  href="#" class="text-white "> ثبت شیء  </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class ="nav-item container col-12 p-3">
                        <a href="#" class="text-white h5"> تحویل شیء </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class ="nav-item container col-12 p-3">
                        <a  href="#" class="text-white h5"> گزارش گیری </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class ="nav-item container col-12 p-3">
                        <a  href="#" class="text-white h5"> Blogs </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            </div>
          </div> -->
        </div>
        <div class="container col-10 border-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 justify-content-center align-items-center bg-white">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-4 m-0 h5 p-3 text-muted border-left border-bottom border- 
      muted"> مشخصات شیء</div>
                        <div class="col-8 m-0 h5 p-3 text-muted border-bottom border-muted"> تاریخ و 
     محل</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col-4 container h5 p-3 text-body border-left border-bottom 
    border-muted justify-content-center align-items-center">

                            <form class="l-form justify-content-center align-items-center" 
   role="form" id="login-form"  >
                            <div class="form-group col-12 justify-content-center align-items-center">

                                <label class="h6 " for="thing-name">نام شیء</label>
                                <input class="form-control h3 " type="text" name="form-thing-name" 
   id="thing-name">

                                <label class="h6" for="thing-type">نوع شیء</label>
                                <select  class="form-control" type="text" name="form-thing-type" 
   id="thing-type">
                                    <option>1</option>
                                    <option>2</option>
                                    <option>3</option>
                                    <option>4</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary rounded" type="button" 
   id="things_register_btn"> ثبت اطلاعات </button>
                       <!-- <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="login" 
   id="submit_btn"/>  -->
                         </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8 h5 p-3 text-body border-bottom border-muted">
                            <div class="form-group row ">
                                <div class="col-4">
                                <label class="h6" for="form-station">خط</label>
                                <select  class="form-control" type="text" name="form-station" 
   id="thing-line">
                                    <option>غدیر</option>
                                    <option>پروین اعتصامی</option>
                                    <option>3</option>
                                    <option>4</option>
                                </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6">
                                <label class="h6" for="form-station">ایستگاه</label>
                                <select  class="form-control" type="text" name="form-station" 
    id="thing-station">
                                    <option>غدیر</option>
                                    <option>پروین اعتصامی</option>
                                    <option>3</option>
                                    <option>4</option>
                                </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row ">
                                <div class="col-4">
                                    <label class="h6" for="form-station">تاریخ</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <span class="form-control input-group-text cursor- 
    pointer" id="date1">انتخاب تاریخ</span>
                                        </div>
                                    <input type="text" id="thing-date" class="form-control" aria- 
    label="date1" aria-describedby="date1">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <label class="h6 " for="thing-description">توضیحات</label>
                                    <input class="form-control h3 " type="text" name="form-thing- 
      description" id="thing-description">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="container-fluid p-3 text-dark border-bottom border-muted bg2">

                        <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                                <div class="col-3">
                                <label class="h6" for="form-station">جستجو بر اساس</label>
                                <select  class="form-control" type="text" name="form-station" 
      id="thing-type">
                                    <option>غدیر</option>
                                    <option>پروین اعتصامی</option>
                                    <option>3</option>
                                    <option>4</option>
                                </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-3">
                                <label class="h6" for="form-station">ایستگاه</label>
                                <select  class="form-control" type="text" name="form-station" 
       id="thing-type">
                                    <option>غدیر</option>
                                    <option>پروین اعتصامی</option>
                                    <option>3</option>
                                    <option>4</option>
                                </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="col-12 justify-content-center align-items-center bg-white">
            <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
             <div class="container-fluid p-3 my-3 text-white ">
                <table class="table table-striped table-responsive-md btn-table text-center ">
                    <thead class="text-warning">
                        <tr>
                            <th>ردیف</th>
                            <th>نام شیء</th>
                            <th>نوع شیء</th>
                            <th>خط</th>
                            <th>ایستگاه</th>
                            <th>تاریخ</th>
                            <th>توضیحات</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody id="things-table" class="text-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">1</th>
                            <td>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-teal btn-rounded btn-sm m- 
      0">Button</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>Otto</td>
                            <td>@mdo</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">2</th>
                            <td>Jacob</td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-teal btn-rounded btn-sm m- 
      0">Button</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>@fat</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">3</th>
                            <td>Larry</td>
                            <td>the Bird</td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-teal btn-rounded btn-sm m- 
     0">Button</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                </table>

                Table with

             </div>
             </div>
         </div>

                            <div class="col-6 justify-content-center align-items-center">
             <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
             <div class="container p-3 my-3 text-dar ">
                <p id="text">.. </p>

             </div>
             </div>
         </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



   </div>

   </div>

    <!-- Javascript



    <script src="assets2/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>     -->
    <script src="assets2/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets2/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets2/bootstrap/js/new/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets2/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets2/js/scripts.js"></script>


    <script src="assets2/js/jquery.md.bootstrap.datetimepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 10]>
        <script src="assets/js/placeholder.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->




   </body>
   </html>
```

> scripts.js

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {


  //login form
  $("#submit_btn").click(function(e){


    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();

        if (username==""){
            $("#username").addClass('input-error');
        }
        else if(password==""){
            $("#password").addClass('input-error');
        }
        else
        {
            $("#password").removeClass('input-error');
            $("#username").removeClass('input-error');


            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'http://localhost:8080/project/authenticate.php',
                data:{
                    username: username,
                    password: password
                    },
                   // dataType:"text",
                    success: function(feedback) {
                        if(feedback.indexOf("success") > -1)
                            location.href = "things.php";
                           // alert("hdgasgdjah");
                        else
                            $('#text').html(feedback);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, exception){
                    getErrorMessage(jqXHR, exception);
                }
            });

        }

    });
    //persian date on things
    $('#date1').MdPersianDateTimePicker({
    targetTextSelector: '#thing-date',
    targetDateSelector: '#inputDate1-1',
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss',
    isGregorian: false,
    enableTimePicker: false,

    });

    //things form
    $("#things_register_btn").click(function(e){

    var thing_name = $('#thing-name').val();        
    
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:'http://localhost:8080/project/authenticate.php',
                dataType: 'json',
              //  encode:true,
                data:{
                    thing_name: thing_name
                    },
                cache: false,                
                success: function(data) { 
                    
                    
                       // $('#text').html(data);  
                                                
                          console.log(data);




                          // $.each(data , function(key , value){ 
                          //  $('#text').html(value); 
                         //  
                         //  console.log(value.des);
                         //  console.log(value.met);
                        
                       },
                       error:function(error, x,y)
                       {
                           console.log(x,y);
                       }    

                // This will clear table of the old data other than the header row
              /*  $("#things-table").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                for(var i = 0; i < response[0].length; i++) {

                    $('#things-table').append('<tr><td>' + response[0][i]['id'] + '</td><td>' + 
        response[0][i]['first_name'] + " " + response[0][i]['last_name'] + '</td><td>' + response[0] 
        [i]['table'] + '</td><td>' + response[0][i]['items_won'] + '</td><td>' + response[0][i] 
        ['pledges_made'] +'</td><td>' + response[0][i]['amount_owed'] + '</td><td><button class="btn 
        btn-primary">CLICK HERE</button></td></tr>');
                }
                //$('#amount').text(response[1]);
                //$('#paymentsTotal').text(response[2]); */

               
            });
       // }

    });
```

> authenticate.php

```
    <?php
    require_once 'class\DB.class.php';
    if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    session_start();
    $db = new DB();
    $db->connect();
    $user_name = trim($_POST['username']);
    $user_password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $resualt=$db->login_verification($user_name,$user_password);
    if ($resualt=="success")
    {
        echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "نام کاربری یا پسورد نامعتبر است";
    }
   }
    $id[]=1;
    $password=123;
    if(isset($_POST['thing_name'])) {

   // echo '<script>alert("Welcome to Geeks for Geeks")</script>'; 

    

    $db = new DB();
    $db->connect();
    $resualt= $db->select_things();

   $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

   // echo json_encode($arr);
    }      
   ?>
```

> db.class.php

```
<?php
// DB.class.php

 class DB {

 protected $db_host = 'localhost';
 protected $db_user = 'root';
 protected $db_pass = '';
 protected $db_name = 'db1';
 protected $connect_db = '';

// Open a connect to the database.
// Make sure this is called on every page that needs to use the database.

public function connect() {

    $this->connect_db = mysqli_connect( $this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass, $this- 
 >db_name );

    if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
        //printf("Connection failed: %s\'", mysqli_connect_error());
        //exit();
        // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
        exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    return true;

 }
 public function login_verification($form_username,$form_password){
     // Prepare our SQL, preparing the SQL statement will prevent SQL injection.
    if ($stmt = $this->connect_db->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE username = ?')) {
        // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), in our case the username is a string 
  so we use "s"
        //$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST[$form_username]);
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $form_username);
        $stmt->execute();
        // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
        $stmt->fetch();
        // Account exists, now we verify the password.
        // Note: remember to use password_hash in your registration file to store the hashed 
    passwords.
        //if (password_verify($_POST[$form_password], $password)) {
        if (password_verify($form_password, $password)) {
        //  if ($_POST['l-form-password']=== $password) {
        // Verification success! User has loggedin!
        // Create sessions so we know the user is logged in, they basically act like cookies but 
    remember the data on the server.
          //  session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
            //$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST[$form_username];
            $_SESSION['name'] = $form_username;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            return "success";
           // echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['name'] . '!';
        } else {
        // Incorrect password
            return 'Incorrect password!';
            }
        } else {
        // Incorrect username
            return 'Incorrect username!';
            }

        $stmt->close();
    }

   }

 public function select_things(){

    
     // Prepare our SQL, preparing the SQL statement will prevent SQL injection.
    if ($stmt = $this->connect_db->prepare('SELECT id,password FROM users')) {

        
        $stmt->execute();
        /* EXECUTE QUERY */

        $stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
        /* BIND THE RESULTS TO THESE VARIABLES */

        $stmt->fetch(); /* FETCH THE RESULTS */

        header("Content-Type: application/json");
        $response=array("id" => $id, "password" => $password);
        echo json_encode($response);
        
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            
            /* RETURN THIS DATA TO THE MAIN FILE */
            
        }
        

        $stmt->close(); /* CLOSE THE PREPARED STATEMENT */
        exit;
      //  echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
       }
        

        
     }

   }
```

Comment: You need to stop manually checking for errors. Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439) and [Should I manually check for errors when calling “mysqli_stmt_prepare”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62216426/1839439)

Comment: i hava not any error in mysqli_connect. data from database fetch successfully but when send this data as json, error was show... anybody can help me