# How to process axios request in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, axios

I'm trying to send data to a PHP file.

I tried adding `{headers:{'content-type: application/JSON'}}`, but I still can't access the data in PHP.

Javascript:

```
axios.post("http://localhost/Contact_Manager/src/fetchcontacts.php",{action:'getcontacts'})
  .then(res => {
    let posts = res.data;
    commit('setposts',posts)
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

PHP:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","contacts");
if(!$db){
  die("failed to connect to database".mysqli_connect_error());
}
$recieved_data=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
var_dump($recieved_data->action)
?>
```

There's a warning in the PHP file:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'action' of non-object in project directory

Comment: You need to stop manually checking for errors. Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439) and [Should I manually check for errors when calling “mysqli_stmt_prepare”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62216426/1839439)

Answer (score 0):

Just change your last line to `var_dump($received_data);` to see what is really received and it clearly shows that `action` is not an attribute (and `$received_data` is not an object) but an array. Hence, you can't use the `->` notation but need to use the `[]` notation to access the attribute´s value:

```json
array(1) {
["action"]=>
string(4) "test"
}
```

`var_dump($recieved_data["action"]);` should produce the right output.

**Background:**
Passing `true` as the second parameter for `json_decode()` tells PHP to parse your input as an associative array instead of an object (see [PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)). If you want to use it as an object (i.e. use `$received_data->action`) you need to remove the second parameter or set it to `false`.

Comment: That didn't help either mate, I am still getting null as output in my localhost. Thanks!

Comment: `null` where? In your `axios` callback or inside the PHP file? I tried your code with my changes and added a `console.log(res.data)` inside the `then` part of the axios promise and it is outputting the right data. However, you are not returning any output JavaScript can then deal with as `var_dump()` outputs only some readable representation of the variable.

Comment: php file is outputting null and my then part in js is also not behaving appropriately as well. I think the problem is with localhost address I am giving to axios. Thanks !

Comment: By the way way my console logged output looks like:                                            
          <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>C:\wamp64\www\Contact_Manager\src\fetchcontacts.php:10:</small><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'getcontacts'</font> <i>(length=11)</i>
</pre>

Comment: Thanks mate , you were correct . I wasn't really anticipating what was happening there. Thank you for being such a sport !

Comment: You are welcome! If this answer solves your problem please mark it as `accepted`