# PHP Script wont update Database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using a MySQLI API to try to make a modify system to change the price of a product. When I try to run this code I see no errors but nothing in my database changes. Here are the code and the table.

[image: Database]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="css/design.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <table border="0" height="100%" class="tablenav" >
            <tr>
                <td class="logo">Mask Emporium
                </td>
                <td class="navcell"><a href="adminpage.html" class="linknav">Admin</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </nav>
    <div align="center">
        <div align="center" class="container">
            <br>
            <img src="images/banner.png" alt="banner" width="100%">
            <br>
            <br>

<?php
//Gets input info for stock manager
 $price=$_POST['price'];
$ID=$_POST['mask_id'];
 
 //Connects to database
 $conn = new mysqli('localhost','teamavatar','teamavatarpass');
 
 //Selecting database
 $conn->select_db("teamavatar");
 
 //Querys the database and updates stock info with a error checker
 $query = "UPDATE stock SET price='".$price."' WHERE access= .$ID." or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
            
 $result = $conn->query($query);
 
 //Simply makes sure that info was logged, if not info must be inputted incorrectly
 if($result== TRUE){
     echo "The Mask Price has been updated";
 }
 

  $conn->close();

 
?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you echo $query what is result?

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: Maxqueue this is what happens when a echo the query "UPDATE stock SET price='677' WHERE access= .3."

Comment: You have an error. [`mysql_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) worked only for the old API. Please consider switching error mode on instead. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score 2):

### Problems

#### Query

```
 $query = "UPDATE stock SET price='".$price."' WHERE access= .$ID." or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
```

1. You don't have a column `access` in your database structure

   ```
   stock
      - id
      - name
      - price
      - inventory
      - type
   ```
2. You're open to SQL injection because you're putting user generated content directly into a query which is run on the database

   ```
   price='".$price."' WHERE access= .$ID.
   ```
3. You have periods either side of your variable so this wouldn't work even if `access` was the right column name

   ```
   .$ID. ==BECOMES==> .1.
   ```
4. Reporting your errors with `die` is not an efficient way to do things
5. In MySQL all column names are treated as lower case. It's good practice not to mix and match cases though!

#### Code

1. You can access the database directly in the connection. There's not need to run a separate function to choose a database

   ```
   //Connects to database
   $conn = new mysqli('localhost','teamavatar','teamavatarpass');
   //Selecting database
   $conn->select_db("teamavatar");
   ```
2. You haven't activated error reporting for `mysqli` which means you have a lot of additional code to *check* for errors needlessly

   ```
   mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); // Comes before connection
   ```
3. Checking that the query completed the way you have doesn't prove much. Checking if/how many rows on the other hand would confirm exactly what has happened

   ```
   $result = $conn->query($query);

   //Simply makes sure that info was logged, if not info must be inputted incorrectly
   if($result== TRUE){
       echo "The Mask Price has been updated";
   }
   ```
4. There's nothing stopping your query running with blank/empty values
5. Again it's good to have consistency naming variables and functions don't mix

   ```
   // Common naming conventions
   $variableOne  = "..."; // Camel case
   $variable_two = "..."; // Snake case
   ```

### Working solution

```
// Gets input values or sets variables to NULL if nothing has been posted
$price = $_POST['price']   ?? NULL;
$id    = $_POST['mask_id'] ?? NULL;

// Check we have input variables before running the code
if($price && $id){

    // Set error reporting and connect to the database
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','teamavatar','teamavatarpass', 'teamavatar');
 

    $sql   = "UPDATE stock SET price = ? WHERE id = ?"; // Query with ? as placeholders for variables
    $query = $mysqli->prepare($sql);                    // Prepare query
    $query->bind_param("ii", $price, $id);              // Bind variables to place holders (assuming both are integers based on SS)
    $query->execute();                                  // Run the query
    echo $mysqli->affected_rows;                        // Print the number of rows updated in the query
 }
 else{
    echo "Nothing submitted.";
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure the connection to the DB is successful? Try adding this under the connection code:

```php
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   echo 'Error connecting to DB: ' . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

Comment: yes it is connected properly, i have other code for removing rows and that works successfully

Comment: Then I'd try what @Maxqueue suggested and echo $query to make sure that is what you expect

Comment: You need to stop manually checking for errors. Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439) and [Should I manually check for errors when calling “mysqli_stmt_prepare”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62216426/1839439)