# In php the mysqli how to compare two table data in different database

Tags: php, mysqli

How to code compare data after done mysqli connect.

> Database name garden_fruit1, password 123456, database username garden_fruit1.

```
$link1 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "garden_fruit1", "123456", "garden_fruit1"); 

// Check for connection 
if($link1 == true) { 
    echo "garden_fruit1 Connected Successfully"; 
} 
else { 
    die("ERROR: Could not connect " . mysqli_connect_error()); 
}
```

> Database name garden_fruit2, password 123456, database username garden_fruit2.

```
$link2 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "garden_fruit2", "123456", "garden_fruit2"); 

// Check for connection 
if($link2 == true) { 
    echo "garden_fruit2 Connected Successfully"; 
} 
else { 
    die("ERROR: Could not connect " . mysqli_connect_error()); 
}
```

Example database table.

```
fruit1 //from garden_fruit1 database 
===========================
|id_fruit_1   fruit    price
|1            apple    3.00
|2            grape    5.00


fruit2 //from garden_fruit2 database 
===========================
|id_fruit_2   fruit    price
|1            apple    3.00
|2            grape    5.00
```

Get connect to database

```
$data1 = mysqli_query($link1,"SELECT id_fruit_1 FROM fruit1"); //database garden_fruit1
$data2 = mysqli_query($link2, "SELECT id_fruit_2 FROM fruit2"); //database garden_fruit2
```

So, I want to ask how to do the compare data from difference database?

Comment: Do you want to compare the id_fruit_1 and id_fruit_2 columns between the two tables?

Comment: i want compare the id_fruit_1 and id_fruit_2 columns between the two database.

Comment: Use `database_name.table_name`

Comment: You need to stop manually checking for errors. Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439) and [Should I manually check for errors when calling “mysqli_stmt_prepare”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62216426/1839439)

Answer (score 0):

You can use database prefix added to your tables:

```
SELECT id_fruit_1 FROM garden_fruit1.fruit1
SELECT id_fruit_2 FROM garden_fruit2.fruit2
```