# Ajax result converting into string doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, mysqli

How can i convert the result into a string to use it in js?
I made an AJAX connection and need the number of all records.

server3.php: The result should be converted to an int.

```
<?php
  $antwort = $_GET['aa'];

  $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','loginpage');
  if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

  mysqli_select_db($con,"loginpage");
  $sql="SELECT COUNT(id) AS anzahl FROM frage";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  $row = intval($result);

  echo "<p>" . $row . "</p>";

  mysqli_close($con);

  ?>
```

js.js: I tried it with this.response too.

```
function anzahlFragen() {

var xmlhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        fragenAnzahl = this.responseText;
    }
}

xmlhttp2.open("GET","server3.php",true);
xmlhttp2.send();
}
```

Comment: You need to stop manually checking for errors. Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439) and [Should I manually check for errors when calling “mysqli_stmt_prepare”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62216426/1839439)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't fetched your result data. After

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

You need to get the column value, which you can do using [`mysqli_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php):

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$count = $row[0];
```

Then you can echo the count:

```
echo "<p>" . $count . "</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **fetch** row from db, something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS anzahl FROM frage";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

// access your value by alias in the query
echo "<p>" . $row['anzahl'] . "</p>";

mysqli_close($con);
```