# Adding a session value to mark a user as logged in

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am making a login modal that will allow users to have access to a specific page once logged in. I have a login.php, a functions.php, and a index.php. The problem I am having is the user is not being logged in after entering the correct credentials, it just refreshes the login. I have the database connected to my site.

My login.php looks like this:

```
<?php require_once("../includes/db_connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/session.php"); ?>
<?php


    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    



    // try to log in assuming user and password are correct
    function attempt_login($username, $password) {
        $user = find_user_by_username($username);

        if($user) {
            // found user, now check password
            if(password_check($password, $user['password'])) {
                // Remove password field from array
                unset($user['password']);
                // password matches, now get return the user
                return $user;
            } else {
                // password does not match
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // user not found
            return false;
        }
    }

    // was user successfully logged in?
    if(attempt_login($username, $password)) {
        // user successfully logged in
        // Mark user as logged in using session value
        // This is where the session variable needs to be placed
        $placeholder = true;
        redirect_to('graves.php');
    } else {
        // Failure to log in given user (username or password incorrect)
        setLoginMessage("Username/password not found.");
        redirect_to('index.php#openModal');
    }
?>
```

My functions.php:

```
<?php
function logged_in() {
        return isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']);
    }

    // part 2
    // check if user is logged in and make an error message if not
    function confirm_logged_in() {
        if(!logged_in()) {
            setLoginMessage("Please log in");
            redirect_to('index.php#openModal');
        }
    }

    // check if password given from the login form matches the current user's password hash from the database
    function password_check($password, $existing_hash) {
        // existing hash contains format and salt at start
        $hash = crypt($password, $existing_hash);
        if ($hash === $existing_hash) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // get the current user from the database using their username
    function find_user_by_username($username) {
        global $connection;

        /* Prepared statement, stage 1: prepare */
        if (!($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "Select * FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1"))) {
            echo "Prepare failed: (" . mysqli_errno($connection) . ") " . mysqli_error($connection);
        }

        /* Prepared statement, stage 2: bind parameters */
        $stmt->bind_param( 's', $username );

        /* Prepared statement, stage 3: execute statement*/
        if(!$result = $stmt->execute()){
            return null;
        } else {
            //get result from previously executed statement - old $result variable no longer needed
            $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt->get_result());

            return $result;
        }
    }
?>
```

I hope this isn't too broad of a question. I have a session.php connected as well.

Comment: Have you done any debugging to find out which piece of code is not behaving as expected? Remember, we can't run your code to see what happens. You need to supply the debugging information.

Comment: You need to stop manually checking for errors. Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439) and [Should I manually check for errors when calling “mysqli_stmt_prepare”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62216426/1839439)

Comment: Your `password_check()` function will always return `false` because you're using the `existing_hash` as a salt to hash the password, then comparing the result with `existing_hash`.

Answer (score 0):

so you will need to start a session and set a session flag to say the user is logged in after successful authentication.

```
session_start();
// check the user via your form and db

// if successful 
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true; 

// use this to check if not logged in redirect else show em logged in content
if(!$_SESSION['logged_in']){ header("LOCATION not_logged_in.php"); } 
// code for a logged in user here ....
```