# Check if database already exists

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I  want the database to be created only if it does not exist. Now that the database exist, nothing  happening but  the following message is displayed anyway: Database created successfully.
I would like this message to be displayed only when the database is created and not when it already exists. How to check if a database exists?
This is my code.

```
<?php
 
    $mysql = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "test", "test"); 

    if(!($mysql)) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
      }

    $myDB = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS myDB";

    if ((mysqli_query($mysql, $myDB))) {
        echo "Database created successfully";
      } else {
        echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($mysql);
      }


      mysqli_close($mysql); 
    ?>
```

Comment: you could query the schema, then decide if to create the table or not, example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/214013/0

Comment: You need to stop manually checking for errors. Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439) and [Should I manually check for errors when calling “mysqli_stmt_prepare”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62216426/1839439)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to create a database with IF NOT EXISTS in MySQL, a warning is also returned.

I would then suggest to check for the eventual returned warning like this:

```
$myDB = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS myDB";

if ((mysqli_query($mysql, $myDB))) {
       if (mysqli_warning_count($mysql) == 0) { 
            echo "Database created successfully";
       }
} else {
       echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($mysql);
}
```

Comment: How can I see these warnings ?

Comment: You can use mysqli_get_warnings(). see https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-warnings.php